# Online Poisson Solver

Tags: finite-element, elliptic-pde

I'm wondering if anyone can point to a browser-based FEM (or other) 2D PDE solver for simple elliptic problems. It seem like there ought to be a javacript implementation that would allow for the drawing of simple geometries, the creation of simple Dirichlet boundary conditions, and the imposition of simple right-hand-side functions. But, for the life of me, I can't find one.

Has anyone ever seen such a system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [NCLab](http://nclab.com/), which has a finite element analysis module using the hp-FEM library [Hermes](http://hpfem.org/hermes/). For example, see the [elasticity module](https://nclab.com/elasticity/).

Comment: Thanks, Jed. I had found this, but I didn't try logging in. I was able to find what I was looking for once I did. Does credit go to the first to answer?

Answer (score 3):

NCLab has three (simple) FEM modules - linear elasticity, electrostatics, and general linear second-order PDE with constant coefficients https://nclab.com/pde. Higher-order elements are enabled but not hp-adaptivity yet. You may still encounter bugs.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! That looks quite useful, but it would be good to state that it is a commercial service with a limited(?) free mode. In the interest of full disclosure, you should also add that you are the founder of the company (see also [this question on meta](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/341/add-software-authorship-disclosures-to-our-badges)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Pavel. I voted your answer up, too, but gave Jed the check mark for being first.

Comment: Hi guys, this is a commercial service (Github-style, with plenty of free functionality). Sorry for not mentioning this explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of blog posts for solving 2D finite element problems using MATLAB at this scientific computing website.

http://www.particleincell.com/2012/matlab-fem/

http://www.particleincell.com/2012/finite-element-examples/

They make use of some MATLAB code from MIT and the distmesh tool for creating a mesh over a 2D domain.

Comment: The question was about browser based solvers, this is just plain MATLAB code which doesn't run in your browser.